# Call fragment from handleValueHelp

Tags: sapui5

I have a input field and a value help funtion

```
handleValueHelp : function (oControlEvent) {
    var lookupSource = oControlEvent.getSource().getBindingContext("lookupSource");

    if (!this._oDialog) {
      this._oDialog = sap.ui.xmlfragment("sap.ui.demo.poa.view.fragment.FrgLookup", this); 
    }

    this._oDialog.open();
}
```

When I define the fragment I want to pass the controller this to the fragment, but `this` in `handleValueHelp` is different from the controller retrieve from for example the `onInit` function. Why??

Comment: is handleValueHelp an event handler? If yes, then 'this' would refer to the input control.

Comment: Ok @sakthi, but how can I retrieve the 'original' controller (the controller that I get when I write `this` in `onInit`)? 
I want the original controller because I want pass it to fragment because the fragment controller is the controller where I have `.onInit` function, `.handleValueHelp` function, etc..

Comment: using js or xml view ?

Comment: XML-View.
I resolve temporarily the proble by `theController=this;` in `onInit` function and passing it to the dialog by `this._oDialog = sap.ui.xmlfragment("sap.ui.demo.poa.view.fragment.FrgLookup", this);` in `handleValueHelp` function

Comment: Event Handlers defined in XMLViews will be called with the controller as a context by default. How do you define the handler? Could you show the code?

Answer (score 0):

Event Handlers in JSViews by default get the Control passed as a context (this). But you can change this behavior easily:

```
createContent: function(oController) {
  ...
  new sap.m.Input({
    valueHelpRequest : [ oController.handleValueHelp, oController ]
  })
  ...
}
```

Whatever you pass as a second value in the array will be passed as a context into the handler and you can refer to it with this.